# Getting preferences outside of PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

I got a `PreferenceActivity`. When a user is changing a preference, I want to save some additional preferences so inside the `OnPreferencesChange` method, I got something like this:

```
if(p.getKey().equals("mykey")) //there is no issue with this if. it enters and get inside to the commit command
{
   getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("otherKey","value").commit();
   return true;
}
```

I also got a Service (which is of course a different class than that of the PreferenceActivity) in which I want to read the preferences. So I'm doing something like this:

```
sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences();
String val1 = dsp.getString("myKey","default1");
String val2 = dsp.getString("otherKey","default2");
```

I get the correct value of "mykey", but always get "default2" for the "otherKey". Why is that? Could it be that the Service get the wrong SharedPreference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("otherKey","value").commit();
```

do:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( this ).edit().putString("otherKey","value").commit();
```

`getPreferences()` returns a "SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are private to this activity", according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As the doc says for [getPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getPreferences(int)):

> Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are
>   private to this activity. This simply calls the underlying
>   getSharedPreferences(String, int) method by passing in this activity's
>   class name as the preferences name.

[getDefaultSharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)):

> Gets a SharedPreferences instance that points to the default file that
>   is used by the preference framework in the given context.

So the the two methods return different preference object, this is why you get the default values.

Change the `getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)` to `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`.